# Cloudwatch alarms strange behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We're implementing some new alarms recently that needs to monitor CPU for 1 min period.
Alarms are acting in very strange way. They show Good status for a min and for the min after they show  Insuffucient data sign

Reason: Insufficient Data: 1 datapoint was unknown.

- Does this mean any problems in the configuration?
- If the alarms condition meet, will fire in all cases or not?

Answer (score 9):

Do you have detailed monitoring enabled on your instance?

If you create CloudWatch Alarms for period 1 minute without detailed monitoring enabled, it will stuck at `Insufficient Data` for 4 minutes after showing `OK` for every 5th minute . This is because with normal monitoring the reporting data comes with the interval of 5 minutes whereas in detailed monitoring, this interval is 1 minute.

If you do not want to enable detailed monitoring which is paid, change all alarms to 5 minutes period and it will be all fine.

I think Amazon should not let users create alarms for 1 minute period when detailed monitoring is not enabled. This is not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this [CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) issue.  To resolve, I had an old auto-scaling group named in my rule that was still running and had not been updated to our new auto-scaling group name.

1) Go into your Auto-Scaling Group
2) Select the `Scaling Policies` tab
3) Check your policy name where it says `Execute policy when`

If your name does not match your current Auto Scaling Group, select `Create New Alarm` and create a new alarm for your new group.

Comment: This isn't related at all to the question. I didn't mention AutoScaling at all. It's CloudWatch only issue